# Reading null-terminated filename from binary file

Tags: python, io

In C, I could read an "at most 16 characters" filename which is null-terminated, simply by reading it into a small buffer:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.bin", "rb");
char filename[16];
fread(filename, 1, 16, fp);
```

But in my Python approach, I have resorted to actually stripping away the null characters and converting it to ASCII even though the characters might not actually be ASCII only, because it seems `open()` doesn't accept `b''` strings, which might have been the result if I used `decode("utf-8")` in my code instead.

```
def read_filename(f):
    return f.read(16).rstrip(b"\0").decode("ascii")
```

Is there a more "standard" way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have binary data with embedded ASCII data, so your method is correct.

Python strings are not C strings. That the data is NULL-terminated makes no difference in Python and the standard library has no methods to read such data, strip the NULL bytes and decode the data like you've done.

The [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) does support *writing* null-terminated strings (`16s` in a `struct.pack()` call will pad the output string with nulls to make up the required length) but on reading the nulls are left in place.